What is the light mentioned in the beginning of the book of Genesis
I know for sure that the light created after heaven and earth was created is not the sun. Why is this? Because the sun was created on the fourth day. The greater light according to the understanding of men is the sun and the smaller light is the moon where the greater light rules over the day and the lesser light rules over the night. What is this other light God commanded into existence after establishing the foundations of the world? Is it the light from his throne?
Genesis 1:3

And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.

I think this light is the same light Paul talked about, the light emanating from the dwelling of God
1 Timothy 6:16

who alone has immortality, who dwells in unapproachable light, whom no one has ever seen or can see. To him be honor and eternal dominion. Amen.

Is the light in Genesis this light that cannot be approached? and if that is so, how did God use that light as an object of measurement for marking creation days, is the day as a result of that light the same as the day as a result of the sun?

There are 5 questions in the Body of this Question. Pick one and ask the others in separate questions.

John answers this question here:
John 1:1-9

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
2 The same was in the beginning with God.
3 All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.
4 In him was life; and the life was the light of men.
5 And the light shineth in darkness; and the darkness comprehended it not.
6 There was a man sent from God, whose name was John.
7 The same came for a witness, to bear witness of the Light, that all men through him might believe.
8 He was not that Light, but was sent to bear witness of that Light.
9 That was the true Light, which lighteth every man that cometh into the world.

John 8:12

Then spake Jesus again unto them, saying, I am the light of the world: he that followeth me shall not walk in darkness, but shall have the light of life.

John 14:6

Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.

I believe the Light was/is Jesus Christ.
Jesus Christ, the "creator of all things in heaven and earth", had to come before His creations.
Colossians 1:14-17

In whom we have redemption through his blood, even the forgiveness of sins:
15 Who is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every creature:
16 For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him:
17 And he is before all things, and by him all things consist.


It would be helpful if you could edit this to be a little more specific: are you saying that Jesus was created on that first day? Or that he was pre-existent (eternally?) but the light somehow began to be emanated from him?

@curiousdannii Done!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Astrophysicists generally believe that the first light in the universe came from "photons," a term coined by Professor Gilbert N. Lewis at the University of California at Berkeley in 1926.
So, let's consider the ancient Septuagint translation of Genesis, which literally begins like this:

In the beginning, God made the heaven and the earth. But the earth was
unseen and unready; and darkness was upon the abyss. And the Spirit of
God bore upon the water. And God said, “Let there be light!” And there
was light. – Genesis 1:1 (ABP)

Next, let’s compare this text with a Wikipedia description of the early chronology of the universe, the initial “cosmic dark ages” that are believed to have lasted several hundred million years:

Before decoupling occurred, most of the photons in the universe were
interacting with electrons and protons in the photon–baryon fluid. The
universe was opaque or "foggy" as a result. There was light but not
light we can now observe through telescopes. The baryonic matter in
the universe consisted of ionized plasma, and it only became neutral
when it gained free electrons during "recombination", thereby
releasing the photons creating the CMB [Cosmic Microwave Background].
When the photons were released (or decoupled) the universe became
transparent.

Thus, according to current scientific theory, the universe was initially dark and fluid. Then, the universe went through an inflationary stage or two, changed from opaque to transparent, and light became visible. All this occurred before any stars were formed just as stated in Genesis.
Imagine that! People used to mock Genesis, asking how light could have existed before the sun, moon (reflected), and stars. And now science has the answer, but it's incomprehensible to 99.9% of all humanity.
In February, 2024, a paper was published in Nature theorizing that the source of free photons were dwarf galaxies, based on recent observations from the Hubble and the James Webb Space Telescopes:
https://www.sciencealert.com/we-finally-know-what-turned-on-the-lights-at-the-dawn-of-time
Finally, science is catching up!

how was that light able to cause a day and a night?

The Bible doesn't say, but I believe the earth was spinning. It's also possible that the earth was orbiting the sun while it was still a dark hydrogen cloud. How hydrogen clouds compress into a high-enough density needed for quantum tunneling to make fusion possible (about the consistency of Karo syrup) is currently unknown. Thus, it might be possible that the original light source was directional (i.e. the dwarf galaxies mentioned in the article). Or the light in the universe was pulsing, providing regular light-dark cycles required to measure the passage of time. No one knows for sure.

This light is the light projecting from the presence of God. When God gave this command, he was commanding his presence into the created earth and his movements to the earth caused a morning or day effect and his movement back to heaven caused the darkness to come back in hence a night effect. I have been researching this light and I had previously mistaken it for Jesus Christ but it is the light projected by the presence of God when he approached the created world. It requires a mind with wisdom to understand these things.
Support for the argument that God made movements to and fro the earth
Everyone knows that for most of the created world, God ordered them into existence by word of His mouth but there are some aspect of creation he personally had to create and the perfect example is Adam and Eve, he came and formed them out of the dust of the earth, this shows he left heaven and came down and formed us personally out of the mud and if God came personally to form us out of the mud and the brightness of his glory is ten times brighter than the sun then this light overshadowed all other lights and created a morning effect and then after God had worked enough, he would go back to heaven with his light or glory and darkness would come back in, hence night

You could well be right - I've heard Christians before say that it was the shekhinah glory of God. But what supporting evidence do you have for this interpretation?

@curiousdannii, just think about it. the only way a day and night effect would be possible without a sun is if God's light which follows Him everywhere he goes caused it, remember God moved to the earth to create Adam because he formed him out of the dust, he didn't just say let there be Adam, he had to personally come and form him out of the dust, now if God is light and he approaches the earth to create Adam then that light will cause a morning effect and then on leaving, the glory of God is gone and the darkness comes back in

No, that's not the only way... God could have created any number of other light sources if he wanted to. In any case, please edit the answer to add supporting evidence.

@curiousdannii, I have edited the answer with supporting evidence

"I have edited the answer with supporting evidence" — That isn't evidence, it is an explanation of your interpretation. ¶ "the only way a day and night effect would be possible without a sun is if …" — This is the "begging the question" fallacy, it already assumes that there wasn't a sun yet. Compare with "The only way life could exist without a God is if it spontaneously emerged from inanimate matter and evolved into its current forms" as evidence of evolution.


When God "created the heavens and the earth", in Genesis 1:1, the original Hebrew uses the word "bara" (H1254), which means to create the essence from nothing.
When God said "Let there be light", in Genesis 1:3, the original Hebrew uses the word "hayah" (H1961), which means "to transform" or "to have become".
When God said "Let there be lights in the firmament", in Genesis 1:14, it also uses "hayah".
When God said "Then God made two great lights", and "He made the stars also", in Genesis 1:16, it uses "asah" (H6213), which means "to complete".

Clearly:

The Sun, Moon, and stars were created from nothing in the beginning.
God transformed something to allow the light to be seen on the earth's surface (e.g. thinned the cloud layer).
God transformed (e.g. removed more of the cloud layer) again, to allow the sunlight and moonlight to be more visible.
God completed the process by making the Sun, Moon, and stars directly visible.

The light at the beginning of Genesis was from the Sun, which had already been created before God said "Let there be light" thereby causing the light to become visible on the Earth's surface.
The days and nights were simply the result of the Earth's rotation, just as it is now.

you do not answer the question, what is the light in the beginning and how was it able to cause a day and a night?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, True.  I assumed the implication was obvious, which is usually a bad idea. Thanks.

the sun was created on the fourth day, that light was created on day 1, how do you reconcile this because logically the sun cannot give out its light until its created

@SoFewAgainstSoMany says "the sun was created on the fourth day". No. The "create" verb doesn't appear again until verse 21. The verb about the light means "transformed" or "became", and the verb about the Sun, Moon, and stars means "complete". The Sun was not created on the fourth day, it was already there.

No the sun was commanded into existence alongside the stars on the fourth day, we do not need a create verb to understand what God is doing in this context

Have you stopped to contemplate about my answer? God visited the earth during those days and his light or the brilliance from his glory which is ten times brighter than the sun would have caused this morning and then his departure , night?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, I'm not saying you are wrong, only that it is unsupported speculation, not an exegesis of the scripture. Genesis 1 uses the "create from nothing" verb in only three verses: 1 (the universe), 21 (living creatures), 27 (man). Everything else is transforming, bringing forth, shaping, and completing things that already exist.
